# bypass boot menu by listing all operating systems at grub menu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2

i have installed two windows operating systems (windows 7 and windows server 12) then i installed  ubuntu 14.04. all are working fine. but now the problem is when my computer starts first grub screen appears with option (ubuntu and windows 7 loader ) when i select windows 7 loader , it takes me to other screen which shows boot menu ( windows 7 and windows server 12 ).

it annoying, everytime i start my laptop i have to go through 2 selections, is there any way i can get list of all 3 operating systems at grub only , so that i can bypass one selection.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) It allows the edit of menu entries contents or even create new ones.

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once installed, you can add the menu entry that you need.

Or

You can manually edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, and add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
menuentry ‘Windows 7′ {
set root='(hd0,msdos2)’
chainloader +1
}
```

Replace hd0, with your own.

For UEFI

```
menuentry "Microsoft Windows Vista/7/8 x86_64 UEFI-GPT" {
  set gfxpayload="keep"
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod fat
  insmod search_fs_uuid
  insmod chain
  search --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2 xxxx-xxxx
  chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Replace x with you gpt2 ID.  UEFI menu entry<sup>[Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=170444)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate thing to do would be tell you to hand hack the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.  (The one that states, `# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE`)

It's well worth a look, and a poke.  You can see how the structure is laid out.  But the way I recommend dealing with configuring GRUB is with the [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).  It takes away the typos, hair pulling, and failed attempts.

Still take a look and give hand-hacking a whirl, but....  I have a copy on a USB stick, just in case I squirrl GRUB fubar.